# problem Stack implementaion using a linked list

Tags: c, stack

I was trying to implement stack with linked list implementation but seems to encounter **'segmentation error'** . The code seems to compile and also run but when I actually enter the value of 'times' int variable in the stdin. The code shows segmentation error. The scanf also doesn't show the formatted string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAME_MAX 40

struct NODE{
    char name[NAME_MAX];
    int regno;
    int age;
    struct NODE* next;
};

struct STACK{
    struct NODE *head;
    int size;  
};

void printStack(const struct STACK *stack);
bool pushStack(struct STACK *stack);
bool makeStack(struct STACK *stack, int data_count);
void cleanStack(struct STACK *stack);

int main(){
    struct STACK list = {NULL,0};
    int times = 0;
    scanf("How many data you want to enter: %d", &times);
    if(!makeStack(&list, times)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack wasn't created\n");
    }
    printStack(&list);
    cleanStack(&list);
    return 0;
}

void cleanStack(struct STACK *stack){
    struct NODE *trav = stack->head;
    while(trav!=NULL){
        struct NODE *temp = trav;
        trav = trav->next;
        temp = NULL;
    }
}

void printStack(const struct STACK *stack){
    struct NODE *trav = stack->head;
    for(int counter=1; stack!=NULL; trav=trav->next,++counter,++stack){
        printf("%d: %s %d %d",counter,trav->name,trav->regno, trav->age);
    }
}

bool makeStack(struct STACK *stack, int data_count){
    while(data_count--){
        if(!pushStack(stack)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool pushStack(struct STACK *stack){
    struct NODE *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    if(temp==NULL) return false;
    scanf("Input Name: %s", temp->name);
    scanf("Input RegNo: %d", &temp->regno);
    scanf("Input age: %d", &temp->age);
    temp->next = stack->head;
    stack->head = temp;
    ++stack->size;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Jonathon could also share me a link from where I can learn how to use debuggers in IDE or code editors please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in stack with linked list implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669115/error-in-stack-with-linked-list-implementation)

Comment: @MANA624 yeh it does but I changed and appended the cleanStack function. I took advices from this too and modified the functions as you see above. Thank you for helping though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your implementation.

You have to first print to `stdout` using `printf` and then you can scan for an input using `scanf`.

```
printf("Number of data points: ");
scanf("%d", &times);
```

And in the `printStack` function, you need to traverse over the linked list with a while-loop.

```
void printStack(const struct STACK *stack)
{
    struct NODE *trav = stack->head;
    int counter = 1;
    while (trav != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %s %d %d\n", counter, trav->name, trav->regno, trav->age);
        trav = trav->next;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And in `cleanStack`, I would `free(temp)` instead of setting it to `NULL`.

By the way... You don't need to, but you can allocate memory for `struct Node *temp` like this (In my opinion it looks nicer):

```
struct NODE *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```